# Selecting custom start date of week

Tags: php, date, mysqli, week-number

22nd Jan is the 3rd week of the year. My course started from 10th Jan, respect to that 22nd Jan should be the 2nd week. how can I find this using MySQL query and PHP?

I am using this WEEK(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.duedate), '%Y-%c-%d ')).

Comment: How can you find what? Start by showing the inputs, then the code you have, then the required output

Answer (score 0):

Week calculations mainly begin from the beginning of a month or year. You can try something like the below code; in this case, the date will be fixed.

```
echo Date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-01-31 +1 Month -3 Day"));
// 2013-02-28
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php